# How do I sync photos from the Photos app to an iOS device using iTunes when the Photos library is on an external disk?

Tags: itunes, photos.app

I have my Photos library on an external disk, not in my user account directory.

The Photos app itself works fine with this configuration.
[image: Photos app]

However, when I go to iTunes after deleting the empty Photos library in my user's home directory, I no longer see an option to sync from the Photos app:
[image: iTunes]

How do I keep my Photos app library on an external disk yet sync it to iOS devices via iTunes? This configuration used to work just fine with iPhoto.